# Can a Multiclass Wizard/Cleric learn a spell at their max spell level?

Tags: dnd-5e

Take the following example.

- Level 1-3: Wizard
- Level 4: Cleric
- Level 5: Wizard => I learn two new spells

**Can I learn *Fireball*?** (*the arcane spell*)

There is a line on (*p. 58*)

> If you have more than one spellcasting class, this table might give you spell slots of a level that is higher than the spells you know or can prepare. You can use those slost, but only to cast your lower-level spells.

Based on the table, it looks like a Wizard 4 / Cleric 1 will have 2 spells slots at 3rd level. So this kind of sounds like "spell higher than I can prepare".

But, from the SRD (*p. 51*)

> You prepare the list of wizards spells that are available for you to cast... The spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots.
>
> Each time you gain a wizard level, you can add two wizard spells of your choice to your spellbook for free. Each of these spells must be of a level for which you have spells slots.

Based on this line, I *do* have 3rd level spell slots, so I *can* cast & learn *Fireball*. The text for Cleric is very similar and also seems to imply that Wizard 16 / Cleric 1 can cast *True Ressurection*.

However, I feel like 80% confident on this front. **Has there been any errata / public clarification here**? The SRD is only like a week old at this point.

Comment: Thanks for closing, I spent 5 minutes looking for that answer and could not.

Comment: You're not the first person - if you have any suggestions for making it more findable please feel free to edit it.

Comment: I also don't know why you got downvoted - it's a great question even if it's already been asked.