# Can multiclass druids prepare & cast Druid spells of any level that they have a spell slot for?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, druid

Question involving RAW.  Basic question: does a multiclass druid know, and are they able to prepare and cast, any spell on the Druid spell list for which they have a spell slot?  For instance, would a Wizard 19/Druid 1 be able to prepare and cast a 9th level druid spell?

It seems like one of the major limitations put on multiclass spellcasters in RAI is that their spells known list is determined by each class individually.  So, for instance, as pointed out in the multiclass rules, a Ranger 4/Wizard 3 would only know second level Wizard spells (gained when leveling to Wizard 3).

However, druids seem to buck this limitation.  It seems like any druid would know, be able to prepare, and be able to cast a spell of any level for which it has a spell slot, even via multiclassing.  So, for instance, a 1 Druid/19 Wizard could prepare and cast a 9th-level Druid Spell.

Multiclassing rules, PHB pg. 164

> "You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class."

Druid Rules, PHB pg. 66

> "You prepare the list of druid spells that are available for you to cast, choosing from the druid spell list.  When you do so, choose a number of spells equal to your Wisdom modifier + your druid level (minimum of one spell).  **The spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots.**

So if I were a 1 Druid/19 Wizard, I would be able to prepare druid spells = 1+Wis modifier, and of any spell for which I have spell slots.  As a 20th level multiclass caster, I would have the full slate of spell slots - so I could prepare 4 level 9 druid spells if I so chose.

Clarifying the decision spell selecting process for Druid.  The rules for multiclass read that you determine spells you know and can prepare as if you were a single class character of that level.  This refers to spells known (does not apply to druids) and can prepare (the number, 1+Wisdom modifier for the 1 druid/19 Wizard in question.  Spell slots are **explicitly** generated by combining levels, and druids **explicitly** can prepare a spell of any level for which they have a spell slot.

Please point out the error in this interpretation of the RAW.  I assume rule as intended would be "Spell slots you have available from your Druid class level".... but that's definitely not RAW.

This is tangentially addressed in this ["Can Multiclass Wizard Cast any Spell"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50424/can-a-multiclass-wizard-use-any-wizard-spell), but only in the Wizard context (where there is more evidence for limited casting) and only by adding words to the rules not actually in the rules.  So this answer does not appropriately address this question.

Comment: I don't think this question is addressed there, other than by a pretty poor response at the bottom.  This focuses on the language of "Know and can prepare" which differs for Wizards and Druids.

Comment: I changed the title since "know" is undefined for druids; I think this gets at your real question better. If you disagree, feel free to edit further or revert.

Comment: You also don't need to mark edits in your question, as the edit history is publicly accessible

Comment: I've corrected the title as your edit was poor grammatically, but kept the idea.  I strongly disagree that this question has been addressed because the other question does not directly address the interpretation of "spells they know and can prepare" as relating to a) spells they know and b) *number* of spells they can prepare.  There is nothing in the RAW that ever implies the source of a spell slot has any impact on rules in the game.

Comment: James, I am not sure what to recommend since you already quoted the RAW in your question.  **You determine what spells you know and can prepare *for each class individually***  Suggest you use the search bar, the [dnd-5e] tag and terms multi class and spell.  There have been quite a few questions about spells, multiclass, and slots for nearly every spell casting class.  The answer is the same (though Warlock / Pact Magic gets a bit weird).  [Here's another example](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73590/22566) with a divine caster. That too was marked dupe, ref to the same original question.

Comment: [This question and answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46478/22566) shows what the benefit is to using the higher level slots to casting lower level spells of the other class. Here's [a Q&A that explains how the arcane/divine spell caster combo](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84814/22566) works.  Your druid/wizard is a divine/arcane combo.

Answer (score 12):

It is RAW, and it's contained in the quotes you've already provided.

> You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class.

So for the purpose of preparing druid spells, you act as if you were a single classed druid.  Wizard spell slots, spells known, etc etc. have nothing to do with it.

> The spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots.

You, as a level 1 Druid, can only prepare level 1 druid spells.  QED.

Comment: This is not true, RAW.  Spells known = all, because you are a druid.  Spells you can prepare = Druid level + wis modifier.  

Spell slots are explicitly created using the combined list, and druid's text says they can prepare a spell of any level for which you have a spell slot.  A 1 Druid/19 Wizard does have a level 9 spell slot.

Comment: @JamesHotze If you already know the answer, can I ask: why did you post the question? (Depending on your reason, I might suggest that you could write your own answer to your own question, which is a practice encouraged here.)

Comment: "You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class."  Rule As Written.  Period.

Comment: If you read the next few sentences in the PHB following Phil Boncer's quote (p. 164) there are examples illustrating which level of spells you have access to.  The examples specifically cover your issue regarding the spell slots coming from your other class.