# When Multi-classing Paladin with Sorcerer, could I Prepare Paladin Spells at my Sorcerer Spell Level (5th level spells max)?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing, sorcerer, paladin

I've been playing a level 9 Stone Sorcerer, and I was about to multiclass 2 levels into paladin when I saw that when you prepare your paladin spells, you prepare spells that fit with the level of spell slot you have. Because multi-classing essentially blends your spell types together into a tasty smoothie (for example I already know I could use a 4th level sorcerer spell slot for divine smite if I so pleased), does this mean I could choose Paladin spells like Geas and Destructive Wave to be prepped? Or am I still locked as to what I can prepare with my paladin spells?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: might want to look at this one: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100336/can-multiclass-druids-prepare-cast-druid-spells-of-any-level-that-they-have-a?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per the [Multiclassing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting) rules:

> **Spells Known and Prepared.** You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class.

A character's known spells and prepared spells for each class have no effect on each other. If the character has two levels of Paladin, it can prepare first level Paladin spells. Any other classes don't factor in.

The available spell slots (discussed elsewhere on that page) also have no bearing on the spells the character knows or can prepare. In many cases, a multiclassed spellcaster will have *no* known spells for his highest level slots. He can use those slots to upcast known lower-level spells.

In the case of a Paladin/Sorceror, spell slots are spell slots, so you *can* use those higher level slots for features like [Divine Smite](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/paladin#DivineSmite).