# Does a multiclassed paladin gain oath spells based on character level or paladin level?

Tags: dnd-5e, multi-classing, sorcerer, paladin, spell-slots

Say my character is a level 6 Oath of Vengeance paladin, multiclassed with a level 3 sorcerer (of unspecified subclass). At level 6, paladins do not have access to 3rd-level spells.

**The character's total level is 9, so does the character have the spell *haste* automatically prepared, given by the Oath of Vengeance's Oath Spells list at level 9**? Or is that level requirement meant to be paladin levels?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and get a nifty badge. This will help you to help us to maintain the quality of questions and answers around this SE.

Comment: Your 2 questions are pretty distinct, and I suspect the latter question ("Can multiclassed sorcerers cast other classes' spells with their created spell slots?", or more generally "How does multiclassed spellcasting work?") has already been asked and answered. I'd suggest editing this question to focus on the first question alone, and search to find the the answer to the second question before asking it separately. Have you read the PHB/basic rules section on spellcasting for multiclassed characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When Multi-classing Paladin with Sorcerer, could I Prepare Paladin Spells at my Sorcerer Spell Level (5th level spells max)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106653/when-multi-classing-paladin-with-sorcerer-could-i-prepare-paladin-spells-at-my)

Comment: Since your second question has already been asked and answered on this site before, I have removed it from the question.

Answer (score 28):

## Oath Spells are based on paladin level

The Oath Spells section of the paladin's 3rd-level [Sacred Oath](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/paladin#SacredOath) feature says:

> Each oath has a list of associated spells. You gain access to these spells at **the levels specified in the oath description**.

The "Oath Spells" section feature below each subclass clarifies:

> You gain oath spells at the **paladin levels** listed.

As a level 6 Oath of Vengeance paladin, you only have access to *Hold Person* and *Misty Step* as your oath spells. The rules for [combining spell slots for multiclassing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting) have nothing to circumvent the limitation set by the rule above.

Comment: Why do you specify the 3rd level slot "you would buy with sorcery points"?

Comment: @GreySage: It was originally mentioned in the question (it asked 2 different questions, one of which was a duplicate of previously-asked questions). The answer should be updated accordingly since that part has been edited out.

Answer (score 5):

All level-dependent features in chapter 3 (Classes) of the 5e *Player's Handbook* are dependent on class level unless otherwise stated.

All level-dependent features outside of chapter 3 are dependent on character level unless otherwise stated.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this claim?

Comment: This could be improved by citing the place in the rules exactly where it talks about this specific feature since such a general statement is very difficult to verify.

Comment: Also, technically don't the multiclassing spellcasting rules (in Chapter 6) depend on class levels? The amount of spell slots you get is determined not by total character level, but by the specific combination of *class levels*.

Answer (score 5):

You would use class specific level. You get oath spells the same way you get class abilities, via class levels. Therefore a Paladin 6/Sorcerer 3 would act as you are a level 3 sorcerer (only **sorcerer** abilities up to level 3), and a level 6 paladin (only **paladin** abilities up to level 6).

Comment: Hi MunixEclipse. This is a good answer, but I think it would be improved if you contrasted it against how you gain spellslots for a multiclassed character.

Comment: @Rykara: I assume that was meant to be an edit to the answer? Or the start of your own answer?

Comment: Edit to the answer, but I decided against it. It was raining out and I think some water hit my phone screen and sent some clicks without me realizing it.