# If a multiclass spellcaster has access to a certain level of spells from one class, can they cast at that level in other classes, too?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting

If a multiclass spellcaster has access to a certain level of spells from one class, can they cast at that level in other classes, too?

Eg, if you have a wizard 5/cleric 2, can they cast 2nd and 3rd level cleric spells? Or could a wizard 17/cleric 3 cast 9th level spells from either class, or only wizard?

Not a duplicate because the question flagged doesn't address what happens if one class has reached a certain level of spells and the other hasn't.

Comment: Does the last sentence of the answer of the duplicate not answer this question? "_You would not have access to 2nd-level or higher spells in any of these classes [...]_"

Comment: See also some of the other questions linked to that Q&A (many of which were themselves closed as duplicates of that Q&A), such as [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68604/35259) or [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106653/35259).

Comment: "Not a duplicate because the question flagged doesn't address what happens if one class has reached a certain level of spells and the other hasn't." - The linked question does indeed address that, in the quoted rule itself and in the sentence below that quote in which I summarize it.