# If you multiclass into two spell casting classes, what level of spells can you choose?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing

If you multiclassed into two different spell casting classes, would the level of spells you are allowed to choose depend on your total level of spell slots or the highest you could have from the specific class? I always though it was the former but Matt Mercer disagrees. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=100wR825ImI&list=PLjJ7eKdrLY350toi0TdYGri-puOdyYCZH&index=27&t=0s

 For example, if you were a wizard 3 cleric 2, would you be able to have level 1 or 2 wizard spells, and level 1 cleric spells, or up to level 3 of both.

Comment: Have you read the Multiclassing rules in the PHB? This is something they cover. Is there something specific about the rules that's confusing you?

Comment: @PurpleMonkey is the point of this site not for rules clarification? I was not aware of those rules.

Comment: That's part of the point of the site, yes, but we do expect users to do *some* research (like **at least** reading the rules) before asking here. See [ask] and [What Do We Do With “Read The Book To Me” Questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5270/14878)

Comment: A very very similar question: "[Can a Multiclass Wizard/Cleric learn a spell at their max spell level?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73590)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is on p.164 of the Player's Handbook. Specifically, you are looking for this sentence.

> You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class. If you are a ranger 4/wizard 3, for example, you know three 1st-level ranger spells based on your levels in the ranger class. As 3rd-level wizard, you know three wizard cantrips, and your spellbook contains ten wizard spells, two of which (the two you gained when you reached 3rd level as a wizard) can be 2nd-level spells. If your Intelligence is 16, you can prepare six wizard spells from your spellbook.

So the answer to your question based on your example of Wizard 3 and Cleric 2 would be that you can known/prepare up to level 2 spells from Wizard and level 1 spells from Cleric.